# If $\sin x+\sin y+\sin z=2$, $\cos x+\cos y+\cos z=11/5$, $\tan x+\tan y+\tan z=17/6$, $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R},$ find $\sin(x+y+z)$ without a calculator

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

> Given
>
> $$\begin{align}
> \sin x+\sin y+\sin z &=2 \\[4pt]
> \cos x+\cos y+\cos z &=\frac{11}{5} \\[4pt]
> \tan x+\tan y+\tan z &=\frac{17}{6}
> \end{align}$$
>
> where $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}.$ Find the value of $\sin{(x+y+z)}$, without a calculator.

By "without a calculator", I mean without any electronic computing device, i.e. just pen and paper. I do not know if such a solution is possible.

I made up this problem. The answer is $4/5$, but I don't know how to find it without a calculator.

When making the problem, to get nice numbers in the question and answer, I let $x=y=\arctan\frac34$ and $z=\arctan\frac43$.

**My attempt:**

Let $A=\cos x, \space B=\cos y, \space C=\cos z$.

Since $\sin x+\sin y+\sin z=2$, we know that $\sin x$, $\sin y$, $\sin z$ are all non-negative. So we get the following two equations with $A$ and $B$:

$$\sqrt{1-A^2}+\sqrt{1-B^2}+\sqrt{1-(2.2-A-B)^2}=2$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{1-A^2}}{A}+\frac{\sqrt{1-B^2}}{B}+\frac{\sqrt{1-(2.2-A-B)^2}}{2.2-A-B}=\frac{17}{6}$$

But I don't know how to solve for $A$ and $B$, nor $\sin{(x+y+z)}$.

I also tried, without success, to use the identities
$$(\sin x+\sin y+\sin z)^2+(\cos x+\cos y+\cos z)^2$$
$$=3+2(\cos{(x-y)}+\cos{(y-z)}+\cos{(z-x)})$$
$$\sin x=\frac{2\tan\frac{x}{2}}{1+\tan^2\frac{x}{2}}$$
$$\cos x=\frac{1-\tan^2\frac{x}{2}}{1+\tan^2\frac{x}{2}}$$

I also tried, without success, to use complex numbers.

Comment: We do not have to assume that the sins (or likewise the cosines) are positive/non-negative. It follows from the sum being $ \geq 2$. If there is one sine (or cosine) that is negative, then the sum will be $<2$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Good point! I will edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x=e^{ix}$, $y=e^{iy}$, $z=e^{iz}$. We want to find $\text{Im}(xyz)$.

We can express this system of equations as

$$x+ y+z=\omega :=\frac{11}{5}+2i,$$

and

$$\left(x - \frac{1}{x}\right)\left(y + \frac{1}{y}\right)\left(z + \frac{1}{z}\right) + \left(x + \frac{1}{x}\right)\left(y - \frac{1}{y}\right)\left(z + \frac{1}{z}\right) +\left(x + \frac{1}{x}\right)\left(y + \frac{1}{y}\right)\left(z - \frac{1}{z}\right) = \frac{17i}{6}\left(x + \frac{1}{x}\right)\left(y + \frac{1}{y}\right)\left(z + \frac{1}{z}\right),$$

which after expanding and simplifying, gives

$$(18-17i)x y z +(6-17i)\left(\frac{x y}{z} + \frac{x z}{y}+ \frac{y z}{x}\right) -(6+17i)\left(\frac{x}{yz} + \frac{y}{xz}+ \frac{z }{xy}\right) -\frac{18+17i}{xyz} = 0.$$

Noting the symmetry, this implies

$$\text{Im}\left((18-17i)x y z +(6-17i)\underbrace{\left(\frac{x y}{z} + \frac{x z}{y}+ \frac{y z}{x}\right)}_{A}\right) = 0.$$

The plan is to express $A$ in terms of $xyz$, then find solutions for $xyz$.

Taking the conjugate, the first condition implies that

$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=\overline \omega.$$

Squaring,  we have

$$\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{2}{xy}+\frac{2}{xz}+\frac{2}{yz}=\overline\omega^2,$$

which gives for $A$

$$\frac{x y}{z} + \frac{x z}{y}+ \frac{y z}{x} = \overline\omega^2 xyz-2\omega.$$

Substituting, we have
$$\text{Im}\left((18-17i)x y z +(6-17i)\left(\overline\omega^2 xyz-2\omega\right)\right) = 0,$$

or

$$\text{Im}\left(\left(-\frac{3164}{25}-\frac{2102}{25}i\right)x y z -\frac{472}{5}+\frac{254}{5}i\right)=0.$$

This implies

$$1051\text{Re}(xyz)+1582\text{Im}(xyz) = 635.$$

The only solutions to

\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
     1051 a + 1582b =635\\
     a^2+b^2=1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

are $\left(-\frac{3}{5}, \frac{4}{5}\right)$ and $\left(\frac{699833}{721465},-\frac{175344}{721465}\right)$. However, as other solutions have already pointed out, we know all the angles are in the first quadrant, so the second solution is extraneous. We conclude that $\text{Im}(xyz)=\frac{4}{5}$.

---

This last step is admittedly tedious, but potentially doable by hand: using the unit circle parameterization $t\mapsto\left(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}, \frac{2t}{1+t^2}\right)$, this boils down to solving $843 t^2 -1582t -208=0.$ Either notice that this factors as $(t-2)(843t+104)$, or use the quadratic formula to get
$t = \frac{1582\pm\sqrt{3204100}}{2(843)} = \frac{1582\pm 1790}{2(843)}$.

Comment: It is nice. (+1)

Comment: It's  $(x-\frac{1}{x})(y+\frac{1}{y})(z+\frac{1}{z}) + (x+\frac{1}{x})(y-\frac{1}{y})(z+\frac{1}{z})+(x+\frac{1}{x})(y+\frac{1}{y})(z-\frac{1}{z}) = \frac{17i}{6} (x+\frac{1}{x})(y+\frac{1}{y})(z+\frac{1}{z})$ , isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

*Remarks*: Here is a human verifiable solution. The calculation (10)-(11) is not easy by hand.

**Problem**: Let $x, y, z$ be real numbers such that
\begin{align*}
 \sin x + \sin y + \sin z &= 2, \tag{1}\\
 \cos x + \cos y + \cos z &= \frac{11}{5}, \tag{2}\\
 \tan x + \tan y + \tan z &= \frac{17}{6}. \tag{3}
\end{align*}
Find the value of $\sin (x + y + z)$.

**Solution**.

Due to symmetry, assume that $\cos z = \min(\cos x, \cos y, \cos z)$.
Thus, $\cos z \le \frac{11}{15}$.

From (2), we have
$\cos x, \cos y, \cos z \ge 1/5$.
From (1), we have $\sin x, \sin y, \sin z > 0$.

From (1) and (2), using the identity $\frac{\sin x + \sin y}{\cos x + \cos y} = \tan \frac{x + y}{2}$, we have
$$\tan \frac{x + y}{2} = \frac{2 - \sin z}{11/5 - \cos z} \tag{4}$$
which results in
\begin{align*}
 \cos (x + y) &= \frac{1 - \tan^2 \frac{x + y}{2}}{1 + \tan^2 \frac{x + y}{2}}
 = \frac{25\cos^2 z + 50\sin z - 55\cos z - 2}{123 - 50\sin z - 55\cos z}, \tag{5}\\
 \quad \sin(x + y) &= \frac{2\tan \frac{x + y}{2}}{1 + \tan^2 \frac{x + y}{2}}
 = \frac{25\sin z\, \cos z - 55\sin z - 50\cos z + 110}{123 - 50\sin z - 55\cos z}. \tag{6}
\end{align*}

From (1) and (2), we have
$$(\sin x + \sin y)^2 + (\cos x + \cos y)^2
= (2 - \sin z)^2 + (11/5 - \cos z)^2 \tag{7}$$
which results in
$$2\cos (x - y) = (2 - \sin z)^2 + (11/5 - \cos z)^2 - 2. \tag{8}$$

Using (5) and (6), we have
\begin{align*}
 \tan x + \tan y &=  \frac{2\sin (x + y)}{\cos (x + y) + \cos (x - y)}\\
 &= 2\cdot \frac{\frac{25\sin z\, \cos z - 55\sin z - 50\cos z + 110}{123 - 50\sin z - 55\cos z}}{\frac{25\cos^2 z + 50\sin z - 55\cos z - 2}{123 - 50\sin z - 55\cos z} + \frac{ (2 - \sin z)^2 + (11/5 - \cos z)^2 - 2}{2}}. \tag{9}
\end{align*}

From (3) and (9), we have
\begin{align*}
 2\cdot \frac{\frac{25\sin z\, \cos z - 55\sin z - 50\cos z + 110}{123 - 50\sin z - 55\cos z}}{\frac{25\cos^2 z + 50\sin z - 55\cos z - 2}{123 - 50\sin z - 55\cos z} + \frac{ (2 - \sin z)^2 + (11/5 - \cos z)^2 - 2}{2}} + \frac{\sin z}{\cos z} = \frac{17}{6}. \tag{10}
\end{align*}

Let $s = \sin z$ and $c = \cos z$. From (10), using $c^2 + s^2 = 1$, we have
$$ \left( -158200\,{c}^{2}+137840\,c+174048 \right) s
= 105100\,{c}^{3} - 
547620\,{c}^{2} + 361136\,c + 117600$$
or (squaring both sides)
\begin{align*}
&\left( -158200\,{c}^{2}+137840\,c+174048 \right)^2(1 - c^2)\\
={}& (105100\,{c}^{3} - 
547620\,{c}^{2} + 361136\,c + 117600)^2
\end{align*}
or
\begin{align*}
&-16\, \left( 5\,c-3 \right) \left( 5\,c-4 \right) ^{2}\\
 &\times \left( 18036625\,{c}^{3}-39680575\,{c}^{2
}+41195280\,c+21436128 \right)   = 0. \tag{11}
\end{align*}

Using $1/5 \le c \le \frac{11}{15}$, from (11), we have $c = 3/5$. Then $s = \sqrt{1 - c^2} = 4/5$.

Thus, using (5) and (6), we have
\begin{align*}
 \sin (x + y + z) &= \sin(x + y)\, \cos z
 + \cos(x + y)\, \sin z \\
 &= \frac45.
\end{align*}

We are done.

Comment: @Dan: Does this look like a correct answer to you?

Comment: @user24096 Thanks. I think it is not a simple solution. Hope to see simple solution.

Answer (score 3):

*Don't know if you did (or had reasons to) expect a "nice" solution to this. For what it's worth, here is the brute force solution.*

Let $\,\sin x=u\,$, $\,\sin y=v\,$, $\,\sin z=w\,$, $\,\cos x=a\,$, $\,\cos y=b\,$, $\,\cos z=c\,$, then $\,\sin(x+y+z) = t\,$ is the solution of a quadratic equation that results by eliminating $\,u,v,w,a,b,c\,$ between the following:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
u+v+w &= 2
\\ a+b+c &= \frac{11}{5}
\\ \frac{u}{a}+\frac{v}{b}+\frac{w}{c}&=\frac{17}{6}
\\ u^2 + a^2 &= 1
\\ v^2 + b^2 &= 1
\\ w^2 + c^2 &= 1
\\ t &= ubc+vca+wab-uvw
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

Courtesy [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/), the equation in $t$ returned by [`GroebnerBasis[{u+v+w-2, 5(a+b+c)-11, 6(ubc+vca+wab)-17abc, u^2+a^2-1, v^2+b^2-1, w^2+c^2-1, t-(ubc+vca+wab-uvw)}, {t}, {u,v,w,a,b,c}]`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=groebnerbasis%5B%7Bu%2Bv%2Bw-2%2C5%28a%2Bb%2Bc%29-11%2C6%28ubc%2Bvca%2Bwab%29-17abc%2Cu%5E2%2Ba%5E2-1%2Cv%5E2%2Bb%5E2-1%2Cw%5E2%2Bc%5E2-1%2Ct-%28ubc%2Bvca%2Bwab-uvw%29%7D%2C%7Bt%7D%2C%7Bu%2Cv%2Cw%2Ca%2Cb%2Cc%7D%5D) is:

$$
3607325 t^2 - 2009140 t - 701376 = 0
$$

The solutions are $\,t \in \left\{-\frac{175344}{721465}, \frac{4}{5}\right\}\,$.

---

[ *EDIT* ] $\;$ The above was posted before the restriction to real solutions $\,x,y,z \in \mathbb R\,$ was added to the question. With that restriction, the only real solution is indeed $\,t = \frac{4}{5}\,$ since the negative $t$ corresponds to a solution with two non-real complex values. This can be verified by solving the system for $\,\sin x = a\,$, for example, which [gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=groebnerbasis%5B%7Bu%2Bv%2Bw-2%2C5%28a%2Bb%2Bc%29-11%2C6%28ubc%2Bvca%2Bwab%29-17abc%2Cu%5E2%2Ba%5E2-1%2Cv%5E2%2Bb%5E2-1%2Cw%5E2%2Bc%5E2-1%2Ct-a%7D%2C%7Bt%7D%2C%7Bu%2Cv%2Cw%2Ca%2Cb%2Cc%7D%5D) $\,a \in \left\{\frac{3}{5}, \frac{4}{5}\, -0.368\right\}\,$. The positive solutions are permutations of the real solution with $\,t = \frac{4}{5}\,$. The negative solution gives $\,\sin y + \sin z = 2.368\,$ which means $\,y,z \in \mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R\,$.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if this $7\times7$ system is more tractable, with only pen and paper, than the $2\times2$ system with $A$ and $B$ in the OP. $-175344/721465$ is extraneous (according to desmos); I wonder how we could know that with only pen and paper.

Comment: @Dan You did not mention the *pen and paper* requirement in the question, which is why I posted the above. The negative $t$ root corresponds to [complex $x,y,z$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sin%28x%29%2Bsin%28y%29%2Bsin%28z%29%3D2%2Ccos%28x%29%2Bcos%28y%29%2Bcos%28z%29%3D11%2F5%2Ctan%28x%29%2Btan%28y%29%2Btan%28z%29%3D17%2F6) but the question is also tagged with `complex-numbers`.

Comment: OP said "without a calculator". I think Wolfram Alpha counts as a "calculator".

Comment: @user24096 The OP said "*I don't know how to find it without a calculator*". They did not say, or otherwise imply, that they knew it *could* be found "*without a calculator*". Then see my opening line.

Comment: @dxiv Ah, I see your point about the complex solutions. I will edit the question to restrict $x,y,z$ to real numbers. (Indeed, I included the tag "complex-numbers", but I was thinking of methods using complex numbers that yield real solutions; my fault.) I will also clarify what I meant by "without a calculator", and whether I know such a solution is possible.

Comment: This answer still does suggest that it would be rather difficult to find the solution by hand from just the equations and without some "guess" as in the answer by "2'5 9'2"

Comment: @Dan I added an edit to clarify the real vs. complex cases. About the "*without a calculator*" part, eliminating variables between polynomial equations can be technically done with pen and paper only. The Sylvester matrix and resultants were known since at least the XIXth century, long before computers existed. It's just that the calculations are tedious, and it's a lot easier to defer those to a CAS nowadays.

Answer (score 3):

The rational numbers led me to wonder if all nine trig values might be rational. That would require each of the three angles to be an angle in a Pythagorean triple triangle.

Then the cosines summing to something with denominator $5$ leads me to consider a 3-4-5 triangle, where one angle has cosine $\frac35$ and another has cosine $\frac45$. And then you ask if several of these could sum to $\frac{11}5$. Indeed: $$\frac45+\frac45+\frac35=\frac{11}5$$

And sure enough, with the corresponding sines:
$$\frac35+\frac35+\frac45=\frac{10}5=2$$

And with the corresponding tangents:
$$\frac34+\frac34+\frac43=\frac{17}6$$

So one specific solution is $x=\arcsin(3/5)$, $y=\arcsin(3/5)$, $z=\arcsin(4/5)$. (Well, three solutions for the three permutations of this one solution.) For this one solution you can work out what is $\sin(x+y+z)$ and of course it works out to $\frac45$:

$$\begin{align}
&\sin(2\arcsin(3/5)+\arcsin(4/5))\\
&=\sin(2\arcsin(3/5))\cos(\arcsin(4/5))+\cos(2\arcsin(3/5))\sin(\arcsin(4/5))\\
&=\sin(2\arcsin(3/5))\cdot\frac35+\cos(2\arcsin(3/5))\cdot\frac45\\
&=2\sin(\arcsin(3/5))\cos(\arcsin(3/5))\cdot\frac35+\left(\cos^2(\arcsin(3/5))-\sin^2(\arcsin(3/5))\right)\cdot\frac45\\
&=2\left(\frac35\right)\left(\frac45\right)\cdot\frac35+\left(\left(\frac45\right)^2-\left(\frac35\right)^2\right)\cdot\frac45=\frac{72}{125}+\frac{28}{125}=\frac{100}{125}=\frac45
\end{align}$$

This leaves open the possibility of more solutions and $\sin(x+y+z)$ not being constant among those solutions. But if you know ahead of time that $\sin(x+y+z)$ is constant...

Comment: But we don't know that the value is unique ahead of time. OP admitted that they made up the question. Apriori I would find it surprising that the value is a constant, as opposed to in a range.

Comment: It seems odd to ask what is the value of $\sin(x+y+z)$ if you don't know/assume it's constant, but yes you're right of course.  I think by Bezout (using @dxiv's first six equations) there would be at most 24 solutions. But still as many as $21$ more than accounted for here.

Answer (score 3):

Best use complex numbers - as in the answer by user51547 although there is a little variable confusion in his/her answer.
See below for my approach - largely following user51547's answer (any credits please give them to him/her) but amending it slightly.

Ingredients:

$a=e^{ix}\\
b=e^{iy}\\
c=e^{iz}\\
\omega=a+b+c=\frac{11}{5}+2i\\
\bar{{\omega}}=\bar{a}+\bar{b}+\bar{c}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=\frac{11}{5}-2i\\
abc=e^{i(x+y+z)} = u+iv\\
\bar{{\omega}}^2 abc=\frac{ab}{c}+\frac{bc}{a}+\frac{ac}{b}+2\omega \text{ 
 , and also }\bar{{\omega}}^2 abc = (\frac{21}{25} -\frac{44}{5}i)(u+iv)\\
{\omega}^2 \cdot \frac{1}{abc}=\frac{a}{bc}+\frac{b}{ac}+\frac{c}{ab}+2\bar{{\omega}}\\
$

$v$ to be determined.

$tan(x) + tan(y) + tan(z)=\frac{17}{6}$ translates into

$S=\frac{17i}{6}T$  where

$S=(a-\bar{a})(b+\bar{b})(c+\bar{c}) + (a+\bar{a})(b-\bar{b})(c+\bar{c}) + (a+\bar{a})(b+\bar{b})(c-\bar{c})\\
T=(a+\bar{a})(b+\bar{b})(c+\bar{c})$

Expanding and simplifying gives
$\frac{S}{i}=6Im(abc)+2Im(\bar{{\omega}}^2 abc) -4Im(\omega) = 6v+2(\frac{21}{25}v-\frac{44}{5}u)-8$ and
$T=2Re(abc)+2Re(\bar{{\omega}}^2 abc) -4Re(\omega)=2u+2(\frac{21}{25}u+\frac{44}{5}v)-\frac{44}{5}$

hence

$(36\cdot 25+6\cdot 42)v-88\cdot 6 \cdot 5u -8\cdot 6\cdot 25 =17[(50+42)u+88 \cdot 5v-44\cdot 5)]$

which gives

$1051u+1582v=635$

As $u^2+v^2=1$, the parametrization mentioned by user51547 which effectively uses $t=tan(\frac{x+y+z}{2})$

leads to

$(t-2)(843t+104)=0$

Hence $v=\frac{4}{5}$ or $v=\frac{2 \cdot -\frac{104}{843}}{1+(\frac{104}{843})^2)}=-\frac{175344}{721465}$

Comment: It is nice. (+1)

Comment: By the way, I think it works for [my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4721123/prove-tan-x-tan-y-tan-z-le-frac176-for-reals-sum-limits-mathr).